# Шаринг по сайту

Tags: java

К примеру есть некий сайт. У сайта есть пользователи. Мне нужно побывать на странице неких пользователей и взять кое какие данные, которые отображаются в их профиле. Какие есть способы для решения подобной задачи на уровне java приложения?

Я гуглил подобные вопросы, мне выдавало в большинстве случае "скачивание" страницы и её разбор. Может есть какие то специальный либы для этого?

Comment: Вот такое нашёл http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=1062424&msg=15220647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, с помощью библиотеки jsoup можно разбирать страницы

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/297597)

Comment: возможно я не понял суть вопроса (шаринг ?!), но если есть ссылка на профиль, которая открывается, то ничто не мешает ее открыть, jsoup прочитав ее html представление выбрал бы то, что нужно, решение не ахти какое..

Comment: нет просто дело в том, что на подобные краткие ответы на stackoverflow удаляют или преобразуют в комментарии, почитайте об этом в правилах. Если хотите - можете просто расписать подробнее пример использования, но обычно просто вопрос закрывают как слишком общий.